# Bitbake gets failed while fetching gstreamer from default offline folder

Tags: git, bitbucket, yocto, bitbake

I am using bit-bake to create Linux OS image for Renesas R-Car M3 starter kit.As per my requirement i am doing it without network so i took all the required libraries and files from previously build images using internet. Everything was working fine till gstreamer library.

I have changed the local.conf and added the following the lines.

```
SOURCE_MIRROR_URL ?= "file:///home/you/your-download-dir/"

INHERIT += "own-mirrors" 

BB_GENERATE_MIRROR_TARBALLS = "1"
```

I am attaching my error log too

> DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'bit-64', 'arm-common',
>   'arm-64',   'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'aarch64-linux', 'common']
>       DEBUG: Executing shell function do_init_submodule
>       Cloning into 'common'...    fatal: unable to access     'https://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/gstreamer/common.git/': Could not
>
> resolve host: anongit.freedesktop.org    fatal: clone of
>   'https://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/gstreamer/common.git' into
>   submodule path 'common' failed
>       WARNING: exit code 128 from a shell command.
>       ***emphasized text***ERROR: Function failed: do_init_submodule (log  file is located at
>   /platform/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad/1.12.2-r0/temp/log.do_init_submodule.9100)

Everything gets fetched from the downloads folder which bit-bake by defaults check either internet is working or not, gstreamer is present in the folder but is not able to extract it from the .tar file .

I am doing all these processes in a docker with "--network none" flag enabled

Thanks in advance.